Configuring uniform permalink structure in wordpress
I am trying to configure SEO friendly url structure in WordPress. First of all, I removed the base of posts, pages, categories, product categories. I also removed the category and product category hierarchy from the url. Only the category name remained in the hierarchical urls.
Example post: example.com/content/
Example page: example.com/content/
Example product: example.com/content/
Example category: example.com/content/
Example product category: example.com/content/
In short, it goes on and on like label, product label, product attribute.
The problem here is that the permalink for each post type inherits from the title when creating the content, that is, the title becomes the url. For example, when the content title of the page, post, product and categories is the same, the urls conflict. Thus, when the user clicks on example.com/content/, it is unclear whether he will be directed to the page, product, article, category or tag or attribute.
What I want to do is to ensure that the site's permanent link structure is not separated by diversity, but a single permanent link structure is used.
In other words, if the product example.com/duplicate-url-content/ has been created, then when you try to create example.com/duplicate-url-content/ on the blog, a number can be automatically assigned to the end of the url. For example, depending on your database, example.com/duplicate-url-content-2/, otherwise it may start from 2 and proceed as 3-4-5.
Can we achieve this, friends? I know it will be a challenging work process, but it will be a big step for WordPress. I'm waiting for your help :)
